# symfony admin filter with join

Tags: symfony1

I have a table, `heading`, that has an `import_profile_id`. `import_profile` has a `bank_id`.

On my headings list page in my admin, I'd like to add the ability to filter by `bank_id`. However, since `heading` doesn't have a `bank_id` - it needs to go through `import_profile` to get that - I can't just add a `bank_id` field and expect it to work.

Can anyone explain how to do this? The closest thing I've found is [this post](http://symfony-world.blogspot.com/2010/01/custom-admin-generator-filter-example.html) but I don't think it really addresses my issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done by using **virtual columns** like the post you found. The virtual column is a way to add a new criteria to filter using the autogenerated filter provided by symfony. It works like this:

1 - Go to the generator.yml of the admin module and add the name of the virtual column that will create and add

```
<!-- apps/backend/modules/module_name/config/generator.yml -->
filter:
     [virtual_column_name, and, other, filter, columns]
```

2 - In your lib/filter/{TableName}FormFilter.class.php (I think in your case must be HeadingFormFilter) you have to define that virtual column in the **configure()** method

```
  public function configure()
  {
      //Type of widget (could be sfWidgetFormChoice with bank names)
      $this->widgetSchema['virtual_column_name'] =  new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(
          'label' => 'Virtual Column Label'
      ));

      //Type of validator for filter
      $this->validatorSchema['virtual_column_name'] = new sfValidatorPass(array ('required' => false));
  }
```

3 - Override the **getFields()** of that class to define it in the filter and set the filter function

```
public function getFields()
{
  $fields = parent::getFields();
  //the right 'virtual_column_name' is the method to filter
  $fields['virtual_column_name'] = 'virtual_column_name';
  return $fields;
}
```

4 - Finally you have to define the filter method. This method must be named after the **add...ColumnQuery** pattern, in our case must be addVirtualColumnNameColumnQuery(not a happy name choice :P), so

```
public function addVirtualColumnNameColumnQuery($query, $field, $value)
{
     //add your filter query!
     //for example in your case
     $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
     $query->innerJoin($rootAlias . '.ImportProfile ip')
           ->andWhere('ip.BankId = ?', $value);

     //remember to return the $query!
     return $query;
}
```

Done! You can know filter by bank_id.

Comment: It seem you write this sample for symfony version 1.1.4 or higher, so you get it done on which version?

Comment: It was made for Symfony 1.4.1 or higher. Not for sf 2.0