# Adding a search box to filter a list of results in Symfony?

Tags: list, search, symfony1, filter, doctrine

I need to put a search box within a list of objects as a result of a typical `indexSuccess` action in Symfony. The goal is simple: filter the list according to a criteria.

I've been reading the [Zend Lucene approach in Jobeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/17), but it seems like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut (at least for my requirements).

I'm more interested in the auto-generated admin filter forms but I don't know how to implement it in a frontend.

I could simply pass the search box content to the action and build a custom query, but is there any better way to do this?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I would like to have a single generic input field instead of an input field for each model attribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made a custom form using the default MyModuleForm generated by Symfony

```
public function executeIndex {
    ...
    // Add a form to filter results
    $this->form = new MyModuleForm();
}
```

but displaying only a custom field:

```
<div id="search_box">
    <input type="text" name="criteria" id="search_box_criteria" value="Search..." />
    <?php echo link_to('Search', '@my_module_search?criteria=') ?>
</div>
```

Then I created a route named `@my_module_search` linked to the index action:

```
my_module_search:
  url:          my_module/search/:criteria
  param:        { module: my_module, action: index }
  requirements: { criteria: .* }  # Terms are optional, show all by default
```

With Javascript (jQuery in this case) I append the text entered to the criteria parameter in the `href` attribute of the link:

```
$('#search_box a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + $(this).prev().val());
});
```

And finally, back to the `executeIndex` action, I detect if text was entered and add custom filters to the `DoctrineQuery` object:

```
public function executeIndex {
    ...
    // Deal with search criteria
    if ( $text = $request->getParameter('criteria') ) {
        $query = $this->pager->getQuery()
            ->where("MyTable.name LIKE ?", "%$text%")
            ->orWhere("MyTable.remarks LIKE ?", "%$text%")
            ...;
    }

    $this->pager->setQuery($query);

    ...
    // Add a form to filter results
    $this->form = new MyModuleForm();
}
```

Actually, the code is more complex, because I wrote some partials and some methods in parent classes to reuse code. But this is the best I can came up with.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this solution, instead of integrating Zend Lucene I manage to use the autogenerated Symonfy's filters. This is the way i'm doing it:

```
//module/actions.class.php
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
      //set the form filter
      $this->searchForm = new EmployeeFormFilter();
      //bind it empty to fetch all data
      $this->searchForm->bind(array());
      //fetch all
      $this->employees = $this->searchForm->getQuery()->execute();
      ...
}
```

I made a search action which does the search

```
public function executeSearch(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  //create filter
  $this->searchForm = new EmployeeFormFilter();
  //bind parameter
  $fields = $request->getParameter($this->searchForm->getName());
  //bind
  $this->searchForm->bind($fields);
  //set paginator
  $this->employees = $this->searchForm->getQuery()->execute();
  ...
  //template
  $this->setTemplate("index");
}
```

It's important that the search form goes to *mymodule/search* action.

Actually, i'm also using the [sfDoctrinePager](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/07#chapter_07_list_pagination) for paginate setting directly the query that the form generate to get results properly paginated.

If you want to add more fields to the search form check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461703/symfony-admin-filter-with-join/5480977#5480977) :)

Comment: That forces me to use the model attributes to filter, i.e. using a different input for each widget. I was thinking on having a unique input field and building a custom query using `LIKE` in model columns.

Comment: That is a totally different answer... you have to iterate for each field and make the proper query. Later I will check if i can do it.

Comment: I know :) Thanks for your effort. I've been digging around the backend cache trying to come up with an alternative solution based on generated classes. I'll update my answer if I find something