# symfony admin list view Sort by username when the model is associated with user_id

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm working with `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin`. I have a model `Poster` which has a `user_id` field linked to the `id` field of the `sfGuardUser` table.

```
Poster:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      fields:[name]
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    filename:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    approved:
      type: boolean(1)
      default: false
    user_id:
      type: integer(20)
      default: 1
  attributes:
    export: all
    validate: true
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: many
      foreignAlias: Posters
```

I have a module `poster` which is generated by `doctrine:admin-generate` for the `Poster` model. Now in the List view, I can see the `user_id` as 1,2, etc. and in the filters, I can see a dropdown which lets me select the usernames. Now, I would like to have a `username` field instead of `user_id` in which I can display the `username` of the associated user and I would like this column to be `sortable`.

On the filter side, I would like to have a text field which not only does exact matching, but also does partial matching i.e. If I filter with `x`, `xyz` also should be in the results.

I have seen some hints about these on some forums but that is all in bits and pieces and most of it is for Propel while I'm using `Doctrine`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your poster module in genrator.yml:

   list:
       title: Poster
       display: [=user, some_field]
2. If you want customize your filter, you can read [**symfony admin filter with join**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461703/symfony-admin-filter-with-join)  and try to do it

**UPD**

It is solutions:

[**Symfony 1.4 admin generator sort on custom column**](http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2011/01/08/symfony-1-4-admin-generator-sort-on-custom-column/)

Comment: that doesn't make it sortable though, in the list view.

Comment: @prongs you are right, I try and it is not sort: Did you try [Symfony 1.4 admin generator sort on custom column](http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2011/01/08/symfony-1-4-admin-generator-sort-on-custom-column/) ?

Comment: that helped..:) you should add this comment into the answer.